# virtual int operator()(int k);

Tags: c++, visual-c++

In the header:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template<class Key>
class HashFunction{
public:
    int N;
    virtual int operator()(Key k)=0;
};

class MyHashFunction : public HashFunction <int> {
public:
    virtual int operator()(int k);

};
```

then in the cpp file:

```
#include "Hash classes.h"

int MyHashFunction::operator ()(int k){
    return k% this->N ;
}
```

Can anyone explain this syntax please:
virtual int operator()(Key k)=0;
I understand virtual methods and the '=0' and what templates are...in general, but I am having trouble figuring out what this "int operator()(Key k)" means and then how it is used in the cpp file, I still don't have much experience using these concepts in c++ so the syntax is quite annoying

Thank you for your time, much appreciated.

Comment: This feature of C++ called "operator overloading". `operator()` (operator round brackets) in this case. Google it up for further info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define the operator() for the object MyHashFunction, which means you can call an instance as if it is a function.

For example

```
MyHashFunction myHashFunctionInstance;
myHashFunctionInstance(20); //Call the operator()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a virtual version of the overloaded function-call operator, i.e. the `()`-operator.

For example:

```
void foo(Base const & x)
{
    int n = x(1, 2, 3);    // calls int Base::operator()(int, int, int),
                           // which may be virtual and dispatched dynamically
}
```